# I wrote a program for finding password from hash, and i have some hashes, but it writes just the last row. what is the problem

Tags: python, csv-write-stream

```
from hashlib import sha256
import csv

with open ('source.csv', 'r' ) as file:
    reader = csv.reader ( file )

    dic = {}
    for hash in range ( 1000, 10000):
        hasher = sha256 ( b'%i' % hash ).hexdigest ()
        hash = dic [ hasher ] = hash

    for row in reader:
        name = row [ 0 ] 
        for key in row [ 1: ]:
            hack = ( name, dic [ key ] )

        for r in hack:
            with open ( 'out.csv', 'w', newline = '' ) as out:
                writer = csv.writer ( out )
                writer.writerow ( hack )
```

my write is:

```
peter,5104
```

write should be like this:

```
alex,2218
emma,4215
peter,5104
```

Comment: maybe because you create a new writer on each iteration?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so in each iteration of `for r in hack:` loop you open the same file for writing erasing previous contents. You can move opening of the file outside the outer most loop. Code should look like

```py
from hashlib import sha256 import csv

with open ('source.csv', 'r' ) as file: 
    reader = csv.reader ( file )
    with open ( 'out.csv', 'w', newline = '' ) as out:
        writer = csv.writer ( out )
        for row in reader:
            name = row [ 0 ] 
            for key in row [ 1: ]:
                hack = ( name, dic [ key ] )

                for r in hack:
                    writer.writerow ( hack )
```

keep in mind that file is open for entirety of this code, and this has some implications.

Comment: At this way we will have I/O operation on closed file error on for row in reader:

Comment: Why? Everything is inside of open context  manager, ergo it's open

Comment: Ok I see it. writer object is created in a loop

Answer (score 0):

from hashlib import sha256
import csv

dic = {}
hacks = []

for hash in range(1000, 10000):
hasher = sha256 ( b'%i' % hash ).hexdigest ()
hash = dic [ hasher ] = hash

with open ('source.csv', 'r') as file:
reader = csv.reader (file)
for row in reader:
name = row[0]
for key in row[1:]:
hacks.append((name, dic[key]))

with open('out.csv', 'w', newline = '') as out:`

```
writer = csv.writer(out)
for hack in hacks:
    writer.writerow(hack)  
out.close()
```